# Wordpress divide meta_values

Tags: wordpress

I have this string

```
$rate = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'tie_user_rate', true );
$count = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'tie_users_num', true );
if( !empty($rate) && !empty($count)){
$total = (($rate/$count)/5)*100;
$totla_users_score = round($rate/$count,2);
}
```

and if i use this string

```
. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tie_user_rate', true).
```

I get all the array vallues of 'tie_user_rate'.

My question is if is possible divide 'tie_user_rate' by 'tie_users_num'
or make something  like this

```
. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tie_user_rate'/'tie_user_rate' , true).
```

Example: I have in "tie_user_rate" a value like 32 in 'tie_user_rate' I have a value like 4. I want to show 8

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot do something like this

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tie_user_rate'/'tie_user_rate' , true)
```

You need to get both values then divide them.
Whats wrong with your first approach, that seems correct?